# Angular2, access @ViewChildren references from inside internal component's template?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'am using PrimeNG DataTable component and need to get access to the elements which are placed inside the column template tag.

In case of manual table generation using *ngFor (no template needed) all is working well but after switching to the PrimeNG component my @ViewChildren list is always empty.

```
@Component({
  ...
  template: `

      <p-dataTable [value]="myList">
          <p-column header="Header">
              <template let-item="rowData" let-index="rowIndex" pTemplate type="body">
                <my-component #myComponent [item]="item"></my-component>
              </template>
          </p-column>       
      </p-dataTable>
  `,
})
export class MyOtherComponent {

    @ViewChildren('myComponent') myComponents: QueryList<MyComponent>;
}
```

I've tried to subscribe to QueryList changes and events are fired after table row add or remove but always getting 0 length '_results' array (using *ngFor array is properly synchronized with the number of components).

In case of DataTable

```
this.myComponents.changes.subscribe((changes) => console.log(changes));
```

always returns:

> QueryList {_dirty: false, _results: Array[0], _emitter: EventEmitter}

**Is there any way to get it working?**

Comment: Have you tried to pull the children based on type `@ViewChildren(MyComponent) myComponents: QueryList<MyComponent>;`

Comment: the problem is I have several lists of the same component and thats why I'm searching components by name.
but I've tried such approach and list is always empty (e.g. only components iterated with *ngFor are visible).